# Slack Popups have started containing escape sequences

Tags: slack, escape-sequences

My Windows 'pop-ups' when I receive a slack message have started (maybe in the last few days / weeks?) to have escape characters in them. e.g. `&apos;`

When I view the message in Slack (web, or desktop App) it's fine; just the Pop-up.

It's happening with my colleagues too, so it's not specific to my machine.

Is there anyway we can fix this?

Comment: Probably a bug. You can report it to Slack.

Comment: @gronostaj Confirmed. It's a known, newly-introduced bug, which they're working on. Does that make this off-topic? Should I delete this Q?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe we should leave it and you could post an answer once they fix it.

Comment: Have flagged for mod input. Happy to delete, or to post update once they've responded to the bug report with a solution (though their initial response suggests the solution will be "download the new update that fixes the bug")

Comment: I have the latest and still have this bug. Please keep this post updated. They don't seem to have an issue tracking board.

Comment: @Yamcha Slack claim this is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to using the built-in Slack notifications (`Preferences -> Notifications -> Deliver notifications via... -> Slack's built-in notifications`) then the Slack notifications will show up properly.

The problem is that Slack messages are HTML encoded under the hood and Windows notifications don't render as HTML, they just show the plain text. The downside of this is that now your Slack notifications will now overlap with the Windows notification popups.

Answer (score 0):

Slack customer support have contacted me to assert that this is now resolved; haven't tested it myself since I'm using @sam2929's solution.